# why is useRef not working in this example?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

Here is my react hooks code:

```
function Simple(){
    var [st,set_st]=React.useState(0)
    var el=React.useRef(null)
    if (st<1)
        set_st(st+1)//to force an extra render for a grand total of 2
    console.log('el.current',el.current,'st',st)
    return <div ref={el}>simple</div>
}
ReactDOM.render(<Simple />,document.querySelector('#root') );
```

I thought it should render twice. the first time el.current should be null and second time is should point to the DOM object of the div.
when running this, this was the output

```
el.current null st 0
el.current null st 1
```

It did, yes, render twice. however, the second render th el.current is still null. why?

solution: as described by Gireesh Kudipudi below. I added useEffect

```
function Simple(){
    var [st,set_st]=React.useState(0)
    var el=React.useRef(null)
    if (st<1)
        set_st(st+1)//to force an extra render for a grand total of 2
    console.log('el.current',el.current,'st',st)
    React.useEffect(_=>console.log('el.current',el.current,'st',st)) //this prints out the el.current correctly
    return <div ref={el}>simple</div>
}
ReactDOM.render(<Simple />,document.querySelector('#root') );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be that you are fixated on **amount of renderings** which is not necessarily the best React mindset when working with hooks. Mindset should be more like **what has changed in my world**.

From that point, try adding a `useEffect` and tell it you're interested in seeing when `ref` changes within my world. Try the following example, and see the behavior yourself.

```
let renderCounter = 0;

function Simple() {
  const [state, setState] = useState()
  const ref = React.useRef(null)

  if (state < 1) {
    /** 
     * We know this alter the state, so a re-render will happen
     */
    setState('foo')
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    /**
     * We don't know exactly when is `ref.current` going to
     * point to a DOM element. But we're interested in logging
     * when it happens.
     */
    if (ref.current) {
      console.log(ref.current)

      /**
       * Try commenting and uncommenting the next line, and see
       * the amount of renderings
       */
       setState('bar');
    }

  }, [ref]);

  renderCounter = renderCounter + 1
  console.log(renderCounter);

  return <div ref={el}>simple</div>
}
```

React will re-render when the `ref` has been initialized with a value, but that doesn't mean it will happen on the 2nd render.

To answer your question, you haven't told react what to do when `ref` changes.

Comment: The ref object is a mutable object the holds the same reference across re-renders. adding it as a dependency to `useEffect` will not retrigger the effect. the reason it logs the correct value is because `useEffect` runs after the render phase

Answer (score 0):

```
class SimpleComponent extends React.Component{
  el = React.createRef(null)
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      st:0
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    if(this.state.st<1)
      this.setState(prevState=>{
        return {st:prevState.st+1}
      })
  }

  render(){
    console.log('el.current',this.el.current,'st',this.state.st)
    return <div ref={this.el}>simple</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SimpleComponent />,document.querySelector('#root') );
```

Output is

```
el.current null st 0
el.current <div>​simple​</div>​ st 1
```

According to [Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render)

**ReactDOM.render(element, container[, callback])**

Render a React element into the DOM in the supplied container and return a **reference** to the component (or **returns null for stateless components**).

Since you are trying to reference a functional component it might be reason.It is interesting scenario i came across because of your question.

Also if used as child component the output is as expected